# Refreshing a page continuously crashes IE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, performance

I need to poll the server for updated contents. So I added a META REFRESH tag to the page. But it seems that META REFRESH has memory leak issues and it crashes IE.

What is the best way to poll data from server continuously? My app is quite old (partly ASP and partly asp.net). I can't invest on technologies like HTTP Push...

Answer (score 0):

Javascript/AJAX. Use that to poll the server.

If you don't feel like updating the page with JS, you could just poll for changes and then force a refresh with `window.location.href = window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the problems with META REFRESH?
Could they be caused by something else?

I've used that method in the past and it is fairly reliable. (Although I wasn't refreshing the page continuously.)

What version of IE are you using? Is it fully patched?

Comment: I'm using IE6 SP2. Can't upgrade to IE 7/8 due to corporate restrictions... :(
I refresh my page every 20 sec.